# Meaning of a sentence in a play

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the sentence said by Derry in the Susan Hill play *On the Face of It* given below?

> In case I see you looking and mind and get upset

Comment: Not enough context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*In case I see you looking...*"

Here, 'looking' is seen as a possible problem, and something - we don't know what from this sentence - has been done to minimise that problem. Cars usually have a spare wheel 'in case' they get a puncture. We may carry an umbrella 'in case' it rains.

"*...and mind...*"

This means that speaker might not like the looking. 'Mind' is not commonly used like this. It is more often in the negative as in "I don't mind if it rains".

"*...and get upset.*"

As a result on not liking the looking, the speaker is upset or unhappy.

Put it all together, and the speaker has done something to reduce the possible problem of seeing 'you' looking at something, which the speaker will not like and as a result become upset.

Comment: Sorry to have been so dim, with my answer below! Apologies too to the OP. I have therefore deleted my answer. I am fully in agreement with what you say in your answer and have up voted you. However, the sentence we have been discussing, would perhaps have been easier for the OP to understand, had it been punctuated appropriately. I don't know how the playwright's script does it, but in my view there should be parenthetical commas either side of 'and mind'.